# Is secure to get the Context from Views

Tags: android, performance, optimization, view

I've seen in the RecyclerView a common way to get the context from the View Parent:

> LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item,
>   parent);

Is it secure to get the context from whatever view?

Sometimes there are situations where we need the Context for calling Services or whatever and I'd like to confirm that getting the context from a View won't produce any problem as NULL pointer.

An easy example is to load an image in an ImageView of one of the RecyclerView items. If we use Glide (for example) we need the context so we can get the context either storing it by a parameter in the constructor or by getting in from the same ImageView that we have to fill.

is it reliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it reliable?

It is. A `View` can't exist without a `Context`. If `View.getContext()` returns null, than View is null, which will cause a NPE accessing the view's object itself